# Google Analytics for iOS 1-time (per user) event tracking

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics iOS SDK (version 2 but will upgrade if it solves problem).  How can I track what percentage of my app **users** have pressed a certain button **at least once**?  I set up a lot of event tracking, thinking this would do it, but the reports are in terms of **sessions** not users.  E.g., it will show what percentage of sessions included an event, so a single user may be counted multiple times.  I defined a custom dimension variable that is unique for each app install, but I don't see how to use that as aggregation unit.

All I can think of is to define my own "one time events" by keeping my own database on the device and only pass to Google Analytics the first time it occurs.  Is there no better way?

Comment: Thanks for the question.  I'm facing the same problem at the moment.   Advanced custom segments claim you can define segments based on users having performed events, rather than on sessions, but when I look at the output it's plain that is not what is happening.   It is scoping on user behaviour in sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Analytics now offers User segment.  You could create a user segment, and use the particular event you're interested in as a condition.

In the context of app measurement, a User is defined as a unique Client ID, which is the random ID generated by the GA SDK when the application first runs.  It remains stable for as long as an app is installed.

More details here: http://analytics.blogspot.com/2013/07/re-imagining-segmentation-in-analytics.html